# Loss and accuracy don't change during the training phase

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, loss-function

I built a model to colorize a grayscale image, during the training phase i feed the network 100 RGB images of a forest, and then i convert the images to the LAB color space to split the training set to L and AB,
Based on the trained AB data, the model will predict these two channels for the grayscale input image during the testing phase.
Now i have a problem, i trained the model with a different architecture than this one with 10 images, the loss decreased to 0.0035 and it worked good, for that, i wanted to increase the size of the dataset to acquire a better result, but in exchange, the loss and the accuracy kept being constant and the model output is a mess,
My code is the following, i wish anyone can direct me of what i am doing wrong, is it because of the optimizer? the loss function? the batch size? or anything else i'm not aware of,
Thank you in advance.

```
# Import images
MODEL_NAME = 'forest'

X = []
Y = []
for filename in os.listdir('forest/'):
    if (filename != '.DS_Store'):
        image = img_to_array(load_img("/Users/moos/Desktop/Project-Master/forest/" + filename))
        image = np.array(image, dtype=float)
        imL = rgb2lab(1.0 / 255 * image)[:, :,0]
        X.append(imL)
        imAB = rgb2lab(1.0 / 255 * image)[:, :,1:]
        imAB = imAB/128
        Y.append(imAB)

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)

X = X.reshape(1, 256 , np.size(X)/256, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(1, 256, np.size(Y)/256/2, 2)

# Building the neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(256, np.size(X)/256, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

# Finish model
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse', metrics=['acc'])

#Train the neural network
model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size=100, epochs=1000)
print(model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=100))
```

## output

Epoch 1/1000 1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.0214 - acc: 0.4987 
Epoch 2/1000 1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.0214 - acc:
0.4987 
Epoch 3/1000 1/1 [==============================] - 9s 9s/step - loss: 0.0214 - acc: 0.4987 
Epoch 4/1000 1/1 [==============================] - 8s 8s/step - loss: 0.0214 - acc:
0.4987 . . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I have simplified the image loading code, and also normalized (subtract mean, divide by standard deviation) all channels (L, A, B) separately, also renamed the variables, that usually helps a lot. ([5 minute free Coursera video about normalizing inputs (will bug you to subscribe but just click that away.).](https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/lXv6U/normalizing-inputs)) So the loading part now looks like this:

```
# Import images
MODEL_NAME = 'forest'

imgLABs = []
for filename in os.listdir('./forest/'):
    if (filename != '.DS_Store'):
        image = img_to_array( load_img("./forest/" + filename) )
        imgLABs.append( rgb2lab( image / 255.0 ) )

imgLABs_arr = np.array( imgLABs )

L, A, B = imgLABs_arr[ :, :, :, 0 : 1 ], imgLABs_arr[ :, :, :, 1 : 2 ], imgLABs_arr[ :, :, :, 2 : 3 ]

L_mean, L_std = np.mean( L ), np.std( L )
A_mean, A_std = np.mean( A ), np.std( A )
B_mean, B_std = np.mean( B ), np.std( B )
L, A, B = ( L - L_mean ) / L_std, ( A - A_mean ) / A_std, ( B - B_mean ) / B_std
AB = np.concatenate( ( A, B ), axis = 3)
```

Also changed the model around, added more feature depth, and a few max pool layers (don't forget to include them in the imports, not shown). Note that the activation function at the final few layers are set to `None` to allow for negative values, since we're expecting normalized results:

```
# Building the neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer( input_shape = L.shape[ 1: ] ) )
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D( (3, 3), strides = 1, padding='same' ) )
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D( (3, 3), strides = 1, padding='same' ) )
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1,
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=None, padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation=None, padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

# Finish model
optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop( lr = 0.0005, decay = 1e-5 )
model.compile( optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['acc'] )

#Train the neural network
model.fit( x=L, y=AB, batch_size=1, epochs=1800 )
model.save("forest-model-v2.h5")
```

Note the learning rate of 0.0005, I've experimented with some values, this looked best. Then the learning rate decay can help later in the training, reducing the learning rate as we go along. Also, I've changed the batch_size to 1 - this is **very specific to this network** and is not generally recommended. But here you mostly have straight convolutions, so it makes sense to update the kernels after each exemplar, as every exemplar itself is affecting the weights from each pixel. But if you change the architecture, then this might not make sense any more, and you should change the batch size back. I've also increased the epochs to 1,800, because it runs fairly quickly on my machine and I had the time to run it. It reaches its maximum around 1,000 though.

With all that, here's the output from the training (first and last few lines only):

> Epoch 1/1800
>   100/100 [==============================] - 6s 63ms/step - loss: 1.0554 - acc: 0.5217
>   Epoch 2/1800
>   100/100 [==============================] - 1s 13ms/step - loss: 1.1097 - acc: 0.5703
>   ...
>   Epoch 1000/1800
>   100/100 [==============================] - 1s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0533 - acc: 0.9338
>   ...
>   Epoch 1800/1800
>   100/100 [==============================] - 1s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0404 - acc: 0.9422

To print the re-colored image I used the following code, please note 5 is just an arbitrary index of the image I picked from the 100; also we need to add back the means and standard deviations for L, A and B (you have to treat these six numbers as part of your network, when you want to use it for actual recoloring - you need to preprocess the input with L_std, L_mean, and then postprocess the output with A, B means and std-s):

```
predicted = model.predict( x = L[ 5 : 6 ], batch_size = 1, verbose = 1 )
plt.imshow( lab2rgb( np.concatenate(
    ( ( L[ 5 ] * L_std ) + L_mean,
     ( predicted[ 0, :, :, 0 : 1 ] * A_std ) + A_mean,
     ( predicted[ 0, :, :, 1 : 2 ] * B_std ) + B_mean),
    axis = 2 ) ) )

img_pred = lab2rgb( np.concatenate(
    ( ( L[ 5 ] * L_std ) + L_mean,
     ( predicted[ 0, :, :, 0 : 1 ] * A_std ) + A_mean,
     ( predicted[ 0, :, :, 1 : 2 ] * B_std ) + B_mean),
    axis = 2 ) ) 
img_orig = lab2rgb( np.concatenate(
    ( ( L[ 5 ] * L_std ) + L_mean,
      ( A[ 5 ] * A_std ) + A_mean,
      ( B[ 5 ] * B_std ) + B_mean ),
    axis = 2 ) ) 
diff = img_orig - img_pred
plt.imshow( diff * 10 )
```

And with all that the images are (original; greyscale network input; network output (colors restored); difference between original and restored):

[image: original rgb image]
[image: greyscale negative image, the input to the network]
[image]
[image]

Pretty neat! :) Mainly some of the detail on the mountains what's lost only. Since it's only 100 training images, it might be seriously overfitted, though. Still, I hope this gives you a good start!

Comment: thank you for mentioning the error above, i was mistyping it, but i ran it again and still get the same output.

Comment: Added more bug candidates to my answer

Comment: taking off the instruction number 9 seem to make the loss decreasing, nonetheless i left everything as it was, however, it's decreasing super slowly.

Comment: are they any suggestions to augment the loss decreasing rate?

Comment: I have changed it to '0.005' and '0.01' and it went back constant with even higher values. Can it be the architecture of the network that causes these outputs?

Comment: Then try decreasing the learning rate. Maybe it was too high. Also, if you want to be more methodical, you should first make sure that the input to the network is what it should be. Use some [plt.imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) commands to print samples of the input to make sure.

Comment: I set the learning rate to '0.0001' and it's decreasing a bit faster than it was, i will wait for the 1000 epochs to be finished, i hope i solved the problem, thank you sir for your time.

Comment: Sure, happy to help! :) Since you're new to Stackoverflow, may I remind you to please accept my answer if you solved the issue, and maybe upvote it too, if you found it truly useful. You can upvote a comment as well if you found it informative.

Comment: yes, i would love to, but since my reputation is less than 15, i can't lol

Comment: That's all right, you can still upvote and it will be counted once you're above 15.

Comment: Of course ^^ ,and i will post a feedback the soon my model is finished training.

Comment: Sure, looking forward to it, would sleep much better if I knew it works now. :)

Comment: so kind of you :), and i hope so.

Comment: Ok gotta go now, talk to you tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for making you waiting, i'm training the model on CPU, so it's gonna take a while until it's finished training, and i will provide you what's new tomorrow for sure, thank you sir so much for your kindness, good night :)

Comment: Good morning sir, after 1000 epochs the loss went from '0.0235' to '0.0137' and this value still pretty high, it didn't decrease that much, what do you think? and what do you suggest?

Comment: First, experiment with more values of the learning rate, try making it even lower, or a bit higher, etc. But I'd go back to the earlier discussion of why are you reshaping X like `X = X.reshape(1, 256 , np.size(X)/256, 1)`. That line is highly suspect to me (along with the next one for Y.)

Comment: yes i have already tried to lower it to '0.00001' and i get the same result, and about the X = X.reshape(1, 256 , np.size(X)/256, 1) i have to reshape it that way to accept more images with 256X256, it's like linking the whole set in one tensor with 256*256*number-of-training-images and X is the L channel and in the same time it is the grayscale version of the colored images.

Comment: Ok so I think that's also a problem because you're _concatenating_ those images into one super-wide image and the convolution is expected to run all over, even at the edges, which doesn't make sense. So it should be something like `X.reshape( -1, 256, 256, 1 )` - note that -1 means that axis will be automatically calculated, you don't need to do the calculation yourself.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the values remain fixed and i went back to my very first problem.

Comment: A tough one... but I'm not one to give up! :) Please upload or somehow send me your full code and the 100 images you're using (compress them first) and I'll try to help you.

Comment: i'll be pleased if you provide me with your e-mail to send you the full project sir.

Comment: That would be info at medinnoscan dot com. I just really hate admitting defeat! :)